# Use first dropdown list to create several dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, list, search, onchange

I write this code using php and I want to create serveral dropdown lists for my webpage's user in searching.Finally,use all choices to get data from database and print them out.
I have already create the first list.

```
<form>
Parts: 
<select name="parts" id="parts" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">
    <option value="0" selected>Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">CPU</option>
    <option value="2">Graphic Card</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Here are other dropdown list.

```
<form>
    <select id="price">
    </select>
</form>

<form>
    <select id="model">
    </select>
</form>
```

Then I want to create other dropdown list that base on different user choice.
I looked for some other questions here and tried this but it's not working. It has no response from the other dropdown list. It seem like i can't get out the value of the first list in the function. I have no idea what should i do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
cpuBrand=new Array("AMD","Intel");      
cpuPrice=new Array("<500","500-999","1000-1999","2000-2999",">=3000");
cpuModel=new Array("Athlon,5350","A Series,A6-6400K","A Series,A4-7300");
gcBrand=new Array("ASUS","GALAXY");     
gcPrice=new Array("<500","500-999","1000-1999","2000-2999",">=3000");
gcModel=new Array(" FirePro W7100, 8GB GDDR5"," GT730, 2GB DDR3"," GTX750Ti OC, 1GB GDDR5");

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#parts').change(function () {
        var part=$('#parts').val();
        $('#brand').html('');
        $('#price').html('');
        $('#model').html('');
        if(part=='1'){ 
            cpuBrand.forEach(function(t) { 
                $('#brand').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
            cpuPrice.forEach(function(t) { 
                $('#price').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
            cpuModel.forEach(function(t) { 
                $('#model').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
        }
        elseif(part=='2'){
            gcBrand.forEach(function(t) {
                $('#brand').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
            gcPrice.forEach(function(t) {
                $('#price').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
            gcModel.forEach(function(t) {
                $('#model').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have to create maybe three to four lists for each of the first list option.
Can someone help me to create the above first?

Thank a lot!

Comment: do you get an error? or what is "not working"? does the onchage fire? can you log the value in the console?

Comment: after i select the first list. there is no response from the other list. they just keep no option inside the list.

Comment: did you try to debug? can you verify the 'onChange'-listener is firing? can you write the selected value to the console? were in your html is the `<script>`? is it maybe _above_ the form (cause that wouldnt work)?

Comment: i add the selected that i want to show in the first. and i delete the form tag . i try to put the <script> inside the <head> and <body> tags. but not working. i add the <alert> tag inside the <script> try to use the selected value to alert something also not working.

Comment: place a `console.log('selected part: '+part);` after `var part=$('#parts').val();` to find out if the eventListener is fireing and if you get a value from the select. (you'll need to have console open to see the result -> F12 or Ctrl+Shift+J on most Browsers should do that)

Comment: you cannot place an html-tag (and `<alert>` is no html tag anyway) inside `<script></script>`. Only Javascript (or another script like vb; what ever you've defined) is allowed here.

Comment: i test it in the firefox and it shows that myFunction is undefined. Also. it response unterminated string literal in `if(part=='"1"){`.

Comment: remove `onchange="myFunction()"` in the select to get rid of the first error. second change the line `if(part=='"1"){ ` to what you've shown in your question. Keep debugging this way until you get stuck with a problem you can't solve, then come back!